# ng-model="model.element" dont work

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

today I have a question, I need to add a value to an input with ng-model = "element" works but if I use ng-model = "model.element" no longer works for me, here the code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as model">
 <input type="text" ng-cero="uno"  ng-model="c1ero">   
 <input type="text" ng-cero="dos"  ng-model="model.eae" >   
</div> 

angular
.module("myApp",[])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
 var model=this;
})
.directive ('ngCero', function(){
  var linkFunction =function(scope, element, attrs){
     element.bind("keypress", function(event) {
         if(event.which === 13) {  
           scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$eval(attrs.ngCero, {'event': event});
             scope[attrs.ngModel]="0,";
             console.log(attrs);
           });
           event.preventDefault(); 
         }
     });
  };
  return{
    controller: "myCtrl",
    link: linkFunction
  }
})
```

and here the codepen: http://codepen.io/fernandooj/pen/EgmQmJ

Comment: don't think you realize that adding the controller to directive creates new instance so you have 3 instances of `myCtrl` and they each have their own scope. Also a really bad practice prefixing your directives with `ng-` ... it implies they are part of angular core. Much better to create your own prefix so you know it is your own custom directive later on when you need to do maintenance

Comment: @charlietfl hi thanks for your answer, but I do not understand how to fix the error with your comment, it will be possible, you give me a help on the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to parse `scope[attrs.ngModel]="0,";` when ngModel points to nested property like *model.eae*. Use angular *$parse* service for this purpose (`$parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, '0, ');`):

```
.directive ('ngCero', function($parse) {
  var linkFunction =function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("keypress", function(event) {
     if (event.which === 13) {  
       scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.$eval(attrs.ngCero, {'event': event});
         $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, '0, ');
         console.log(attrs);
       });
       event.preventDefault(); 
     }
 });
};
return {
  controller: "myCtrl",
  link: linkFunction
}
})
```